# Positioning list elements using grid in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to implement a grid in css which contains two rows, first row has 3 columns which each columns contain one of the li elements, and the second row contains the fourth li element from the unordered list. I am required to not modify the html code. Ps. this is for learning purpose so any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
.unordered_list {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="unordered_list">
  <li>
      <img src="logo.png" alt="car">
      <p>It should be column of 3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src="logo.png" alt="car">
      <p>It should be column of 3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src="logo.png" alt="car">
      <p>It should be column of 3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
      <h2>Head H2 Text</h2>
      <p>Should be a row</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a sectioned grid/list with <li> and <hr> with html/css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557314/how-to-create-a-sectioned-grid-list-with-li-and-hr-with-html-css)

Comment: First of all this is a duplicate... and secondly if you took the time to read any fundamental documentation, and/or basic tutorials you would not be asking this. Here is a page that already attempts to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557314/how-to-create-a-sectioned-grid-list-with-li-and-hr-with-html-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw your columns and rows using `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` on the container element.

then specify the start and end of each grid item using `grid-column: <start-line> / <end-line>` and `grid-row: <start-line> / <end-line>`

**[Click here for a strong well illustrated guide to use Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)**

and preview the snippet I included for a solution for your needed grid.

---

### **Snippet is edited to more simple solution

```css
.unordered_list {
  display: grid;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px [col-start]);
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.unordered_list li:last-child {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
```

```html
<ul class="unordered_list">
  <li>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="car">
    <p>It should be column of 3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="car">
    <p>It should be column of 3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="car">
    <p>It should be column of 3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Head H2 Text</h2>
    <p>Should be a row</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is it any way without modifying the html, i can't add classes nor identifiers.

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori you can use `:nth-child` for elements https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/. let me try to apply it to my example and I will comment again when edited

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori I made you a solution. please see the snippet in my answer. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use grid areas:

```css
.unordered_list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b c"
    "d d d";
}
.a {
  grid-area: a;
}
.b {
  grid-area: b;
}
.c {
  grid-area: c;
}
.d {
  grid-area: d;
}
```

```html
<ul class="unordered_list">
      <li class="a">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="car" />
        <p>It should be column of 3</p>
      </li>
      <li class="b">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="car" />
        <p>It should be column of 3</p>
      </li>
      <li class="c">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="car" />
        <p>It should be column of 3</p>
      </li>
      <li class="d">
        <h2>Head H2 Text</h2>
        <p>Should be a row</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out a CSS Grid generator like [this one](https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.com/), it will make it a lot easier to visualize. It'll spit out the base code for you and then you should be able to figure it out from there.